# To bundle translation files or not to bundle?

Tags: javascript, web, localization, internationalization

What’s suggested to be best for website localization?
To bundle all language files or load the files on request?

Which pattern is used most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems both approaches are valid and also offered by translation management systems like https://locize.com

You can either export the translation files and bundle them in the app or directly serve the files by the CDN.

Answer (score 0):

> To bundle all language files

There is no need to bundle all languages and return it to the clients.

> load the files on request?

If your pages are Server Side Render ( SSR ) then set the localization values in the page 
at that time based on the `Accept-Language` header in the request. If no `Accept-Language` header is present then set the default `Accept-Language` as per your business requirement or country you are operating.

If pages are client side render in that case also localization values are set in `index.html` as soon it's serve from backend because if you request the file after it's render in the browser user has wait for the page to shown till localizations are fetch.

Read more from mdn documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language